# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate object inside a nested array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

> This is my schema

```
var tlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id:String,
    name:String,
    cost:Number,
    rows:Number,
    spr:Number,
    screen:[{
        _id:String,
        date:String,
        time:String,
        layout:[{
            _id:String,
            seatno:String,
            booked:Boolean
    }]
  }]            
})
var tl = mongoose.model("tl",tlSchema);
```

> I want to update booked field inside of layout array inside of
>   screen array, this is my query

```
tl.findOneAndUpdate({ "screen._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e22694c","screen.layout._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e226974"},
{"$set":{"screen.0.layout.$.booked":false}}
,function(err,v){
        if(err){console.log(err)}else{
            console.log(v)
        }
})
```

> I'm not getting any error and also my data is not getting updated
>   please help

Comment: neither screen nor layout have an _id in the schema?

Comment: sorry my mistake , I updated the schema

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is update a specific element in an array that is contained in a specific element of another array.

You can use `arrayFilters` to achieve what you want.

The options object here defines 2 filters, one for each array, and the `$set` in the update uses these filters to only affect matching elements from each array:

```
tl.findOneAndUpdate({ "screen._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e22694c","screen.layout._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e226974"},
{"$set":{"screen.$[screenFilter].layout.$[layoutFilter].booked":false}},
{"arrayFilters":[
     {"screenFilter._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e22694c"},
     {"layoutFilter._id":"5e9385432bdc30062e226974"}
]},
function(err,v){
        if(err){console.log(err)}else{
            console.log(v)
        }
})
```